# Count the values from a variable column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem writing down a formula or a script in Google Sheet or Google App Script to find and count the values in a sheet where the number and references to the columns change.

I have a script that copy&paste the Sheet files for the staff shifts of every week from a Drive folder and merge them side by side (in horizontal).

In this sheet that contains all the shifts merged I want to count all the cells of the staff filtered only for handler and picker (column B, K, etc.) according to a specific date (row 3) for every hour.

[image]

Example: if today is 28/10/2020 find the right column with the same date in row 3 --> column E, count all the values from row 4 filtered by picker or handler for every hour (10 people at 05 AM).

Do you think that I can implement this with a formula (like a matrix, vlookup, etc.) or should it be written as a Script?

Thank you very much,
Marco

Comment: Please don't tag with Excel if you don't use Excel. They are not the same.

Comment: So, you want to count items from column containing `28/10/2010`?

Comment: Just my two cents: I have a difficult time understanding your question. I would like to help. But I am not interested in your particular task. I think some abstraction on exactly what generic problem you are facing would be helpful in attracting answers.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following

```
=COUNTA(QUERY({A3:I;J3:R},"select Col"&MATCH(A1,A3:I3)&" 
                           where Col2 matches 'Technician|Picker' "))
```

Where `B1` holds the date you wish to search for (`28/10/2010`)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below formula. Replace date with your search date.

```
=COUNTA(INDEX(A4:R14,,MATCH(DATE(2020,10,28),A3:R3)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was earlier tagged as excel. This is how to "tackle" this in excel (office 365):
In a clear column use the following formula to get the unique hour-values that are in the column that equal today:
`=UNIQUE(FILTER(INDEX(($4:$1048576,,MATCH(TODAY(),$3:$3,0)),INDEX(($4:$1048576,,MATCH(TODAY(),$3:$3,0))<>""))`
In the column next to that type the following to get the result of the count of those unique values for that day:
`=COUNTIF(INDEX(($4:$1048576,,MATCH(TODAY(),$3:$3,0)), FILTER (I:I,I:I<>""))`
Where `I:I` in `FILTER (I:I,I:I<>"")` needs to be changed into the column you put the first formula.